# Define constant inside #ifdef in C

Tags: c, macos, constants

I want to define a constant depending on the OS in use.
As such:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _Win32        //Used for system("cls") command
#include <process.h>
#define CLEAR "system(\"cls\")"
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
#define CLEAR "system(\"clear\")"
#endif

int main()
{
   CLEAR;
}
```

Xcode gives me an error stating that expression result unused at
`#define CLEAR "system(\"clear\")` and inside the main function.

I am on a Mac.

Comment: yeah lovely; fork a process to clear the screen....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#define CLEAR system("clear")
```

not

```
#define CLEAR "system(\"clear\")"
```

You get the error because your macro call is substituted with:

```
"system(\"clear\")";
```

which is a useless expression statement (the expression being the string here) like for example:

```
0;   // valid but pointless
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CLEAR system("clear")
```

and not

```
#define CLEAR "system(\"clear\")"
```

The compiler will create a new C code (called pre-processor code) in which will replace the macro name by its content.

so if you define macro in this way:

```
 #define CLEAR "system(\"clear\")"
```

You will get in the new code (pre-processor code) generated by the Compiler:

```
int main()
{
    "system(\"clear\")";

}
```

You can see the code generated by the compiler (pre-processor code) with `gcc -E`

Answer (score 0):

try altering your main function as such:

```
int main()
{
    int rc;
    rc = CLEAR;
    return rc;
}
```

You need to catch the return value of the system() call and use it